# Camunda n eyes principle

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

While there are a lot of examples around on how to model a four eyes principle with Camunda, i am looking for a solution to model a *n* eyes principle. More specifically, i want at least *n* users to approve or decline a certain task.

My first approach uses a parallel multi instance, but i am not certain if this is modelled correctly. Also, i want to use a dynamic expression to determine if the task is approved or declined (e.g. if *n = 3* and at least *2* users approved).

Can someone clarify? Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]